# Поиск последовательности разделителей (символов) в тексте

Tags: c, текст, text

Всем доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы задать вопрос, который у меня как у неопытного программиста вызвал сложность. Суть задания в том, что изначально вводится текст из файла и массив разделителей с клавиатуры. затем нужно выполнить два преобразования: первое - найти в тексте введённую последовательность разделителей и, при нахождении её более трёх раз, перемена мест всех нечётных строк по кругу, второе - удаление в нечётных строках всех слов, превышающих указанное пользователем ограничение длины.

На данный момент я смог реализовать ввод текста и разделителей, поиск нечётных строк и функцию поиска, которая успешно работает с единичными символами, но не может найти в тексте последовательность разделителей из массива.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void symcount(char, char, int, int);
int main(void)
 {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
const int numberOfCharactersToRead = 128;
char* inputText = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfCharactersToRead));
FILE *fp;
fopen_s(&fp, "D:\\texxxt.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("\nФайл не найден\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
fgets(inputText, numberOfCharactersToRead, fp);
printf("Введите последовательность разделителей: ");
const int numberOfDelimitersToRead = 6;
char* delimiters = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfDelimitersToRead));
int indexer = 0;
for (indexer = 0; indexer < numberOfDelimitersToRead; indexer++)
{
    delimiters[indexer] = getchar();
}

printf("\n Выведем нечётные строки для наглядности:");
//Вывод нечетных строк с указанием номеров строк
int c;  
int y = 1;
int newline = 1;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if (y % 2 == 1)
    {
        if (newline)
        {
            printf("%03d | ", y );
        }
        printf("%c", c );
    }
    newline = (c == '\n');
    if (newline)
    {
        y++;
    }
}
printf("\n");
system("pause");


//Считаем количество разделителей (вот тут и кроется проблема)
int count = 0, inx;
scanf_s("%p", &inputText); 
scanf_s("%p", &delimiters); //ищем в тексте разделители
for (inx = 0; inputText[inx] != '\0'; inx++) {
        if (inputText[inx] == delimiters[indexer])
            count++;
    }
if (count == 0)
    printf("\nDeliniters '%p'are not present", delimiters);
else
    printf("\nOccurence of delimiters '%c' : %d", delimiters, count);
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за предложенные идеи. Простите, если мои вопросы показались слишком уж глупыми :)

Comment: Уточните: 1) нужно искать *любой* из разделителей или точную последовательность? 2) если в качестве разделителей задана строка `".,!?"`, то что делать при нахождении последовательности `"???"` - считать, что нашли три вхождения или одно?

Comment: 1) Точную последовательность, которую пользователь вводит с клавиатуры. 2) Думаю, что три вхождения

Comment: Тогда вообще непонятно в чём проблема: [man strstr](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strstr&category=3&russian=0).

Comment: См. дополнение в ответе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Возвращает количество разделителей в строке.
 * Разделители, идущие подряд, считаем одним.
 * Проще было бы использовать strtok(), но мы не хотим
 * модифицировать исходную строку.
 */
static size_t delimiters_count(const char * s, const char * delim) {
    size_t ndelim = 0;
    char * token = strpbrk(s, delim);
    while (token) {
        ndelim++;
        /*
         * Пропускаем разделители, следующие за текущим:
         */
        while (*token && strchr(delim, *token)) {
            token++;
        }
        if (!*token) {
            break;
        }
        token = strpbrk(token, delim);
    }
    return ndelim;
}

/*
 * Пробуем:
 */
int main() {
    /* Должны найти:          1      2     3 4     5 */
    const char text[] = "Hello, world!\nLet's dance?";
    const char delim[] = " :;,.!?'\n\r\t";

    printf("Delimiters found: %zu\n", delimiters_count(text, delim));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Вариант для точного вхождения разделителя (хотя он как минимум странный с практической точки зрения):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Возвращает количество вхождений заданной подстроки в строку.
 */
static size_t substring_count(const char * string, const char * substring) {
    size_t nsubstr = 0;
    size_t dlen = strlen(substring);
    char * token = strstr(string, substring);
    while (token) {
        nsubstr++;
        token += dlen;
        token = strstr(token, substring);
    }
    return nsubstr;
}

/*
 * Проверяем:
 */
int main() {
    /* Должны найти:     12      3     4 */
    char text[] = "Hello,  world! Let's dance?";
    char substring[] = " ";

    printf("Substrings found: %zu\n", substring_count(text, substring));
    return 0;
}
```